# How to store user ID of one person to other table in database?

Tags: php, android, database, retrofit

I have 2 tables in database user_info and product_info.I save user_id,name,email,etc in user_info and product_id,product_name,product_description in product info.Now I have to look for a particular product so how do I get which product was uploaded by whom.How to link user_info with product_info in Android

Comment: You can add `user_id` field in product info table so when you create a product you can add user_id to it and when you retrieve product info you will have `user_id` to look up info for that user `user_info` table.hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you have two approaches

1. you need to create a pivot table having three fields as table `user_product_info` with fields: `id` , `user_id` and `product_id`. You can set user_id and product_id which is related. here id is a primary key which you can use for further things.
2. or you can create a field user_id in product_info table and can use that.

Hope it helps you.